# Woocommerce wp-admin search products through custom meta value too

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, metabox, search

Right now I can search only through title and content.

How can I search also through a custom meta box value?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  There are plugins that can add this functionality, I have used [SearchWP](https://searchwp.com/) in the past, it works well with WooCommerce.

You could also write your own custom function and add it to your theme's functions.php file.  Something like this should work.

```
function my_custom_search( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( $query->is_search() ) { 

            $meta_query = array(
                'key'       => 'custom_meta',
                'value'     => $query->query['s'],
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'  
            );

            $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

        }
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts' , 'my_custom_search');
```

Comment: Is this for the wp-admin screen? Here /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product ?

Comment: My bad, I misread your question.  Try [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/) I just tried it and it works well in the admin.  Go into the setting and check to allow custom field meta.

Comment: it works well in the frontend, but in the wp-admin it doesn't work.